# what is the correct pattern syntax for `git rev-list`'s branches and glob?

Tags: git

I cannot get `--glob=<glob-pattern>` and `--branches[=<pattern>]` to work

> Pretend as if all the refs in refs/heads are listed on the command line as . If  is given, limit branches to ones matching given shell glob. If pattern lacks ?, *, or [, /* at the end is implied.

> Pretend as if all the refs matching shell glob  are listed on the command line as . Leading refs/, is automatically prepended if missing. If pattern lacks ?, *, or [, /* at the end is implied.

```
$ git show-ref --heads
d1a4464bf5e13cc9926ce4c19f607053f939b10e refs/heads/master
4462283db504c4efdc76e3a587a79a186b6425ad refs/heads/my-test
64b2b14d3123c619db5bbfac718c579e8daa8da8 refs/heads/my-test2
```

`git rev-list --simplify-by-decoration --format='%D' --glob='refs/heads/my-test'` show nothing.

`git rev-list --simplify-by-decoration --format='%D' --branches=master` also show nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

It's not a bug, it's acting as documented. Take a close look at the docs for `--branches` here (the docs for `--glob` use the same language):

> `--branches[=<pattern>]`
>
> Pretend as if all the refs in refs/heads are listed on the command line as . If
>  is given, limit branches to ones matching given shell glob. **If pattern lacks `?`,
> `*`, or `[`, `/*` at the end is implied.**

Look in particular at the highlighted part at the end: if you don't include a globbing character, then it appends `/*` to the end of your expression. That means the following works just fine:

```
git rev-list --glob='refs/heads'
```

Because that gets translated into:

```
git rev-list --glob='refs/heads/*'
```

---

### Previously...

That seems like a bug, because while `refs/heads/my-test` isn't really a glob pattern (there are no globbing characters in it), it ought to match itself.

If you rewrite your command as:

```
git rev-list --simplify-by-decoration --format='%D' --glob='refs/heads/my-test*'
```

The the command should act as if both `my-test` and `my-test2` were specified on the command line.

---

The second example can be "solved" the same way; if you run:

```
git rev-list --simplify-by-decoration --format='%D' --branches='master*'
```

It should work as you expect.

---

At the moment, the implication is that if you want a single reference, don't use a globbing operator like `--glob` or `--branches`; just specify the ref directly:

```
git rev-list --simplify-by-decoration --format='%D' refs/heads/master
```

Comment: I am wrapping the command with a script language. In most cases we have the glob characters but in some cases we do not have it. I guess we have to preprocess the request when there is no real glob pattern we need to drop the `--glob`